# C# Method overriding with delegates as parameters, compiler is not infering the input types

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, overriding

Can you please help me here, why the compiler does not infer the lambda input parameter right?

Example:

```
void Test(Action<string> n)
{
}
void Test(Action<int,string> n)
{
}
```

Ok so when doing this:

```
obj.Test(x=>{}); // compiler doesn't know x is a string
```

If I do this:

```
obj.Test((x,y)=>{}); // that works, compiler know x is a int and y is a string
```

Looks like I will have to specify the input parameter type (?)

```
obj.Test((string x) => {}) // <-- Prefer not doing this
```

So any reasons why the compiler can't get the type right?

Thanks!
Carlos

Comment: I can only assume you have an additional `Test` method that you failed to share with us.  As when I tried your code, I did not get any problems with your first option, `obj.Test(x=>{});`.  (vs2010, .net4)

Comment: Yes, maybe you have another method `Test(Action<WhatEverType> n)` ...

Comment: Hmmm this is strange, I'm using Visual Studio 2008, check the screen shot, can you see the intellisense with missing string properties?
http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/9523/overr.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried to recreate the problem with Visual Studio 2008, and did a screen capture here: http://screencast.com/t/YTAwNmQ4M

I was not able to reproduce the problem. I have seen Visual Studio do things like this in the past, but building always works, and often it is a memory issue. Closing Visual Studio, along with other programs that might be taking a lot of memory, and then starting Visual Studio back up has often helped.

So, basically, my answer is, "did you try turning on off, and then back on again?"

Comment: Looks like my VS is corrupted, when I place the mouse over the parameter it does says (parameter) string x, but the autocomplete desn't show the string methods and properties, ahh, I don't want to reinstall...

Comment: Restarted the machine and still same problem, well thank you anyway. I want to set the correct answer to both of you but that's not possible i think.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshot, the problem is quite simple.  Your method name `Test` is the same as the enclosing class, `Test`.  This is not allowed, and in fact, you should receive the compiler error:

> 'Test': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

Comment: Sorry about that, I wrote that very quickly, look at this example with correct names: http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/6766/overrb.png

Comment: @carlosdubusm, Hmm, doesn't happen for me:  http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/9323/60539152.png  (using vs2008 now too)

Comment: @carlosdubusm, to shed some more light on the problem, try invoking one of the string methods that *should* be there, and then compile it and see what the compiler error is.

Comment: Yeah, calling x.Length compiled correctly, but still the properties are not shown in the autocomplete dialog, so the problem is in my VS2008 right?

Comment: @carlosdubusm, do you have any plugins installed?  And I assume you've already tried shutting down VS and restarting?